# Do I want to perform a function on my app flutter whenever the app is closed by the user?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, onesignal

I developed an app with flutter, which has a chat and notification system with OneSignal, in this app, the playerId is registered the first time the app is opened, and linked to a user when he logs into the system.

The user also has the option to stay logged in!

Use case:

When the user chooses to stay logged in, that's fine, as he will receive your chat notifications normally.
But when he chooses not to log in I am facing a problem.

While he is using the app he should be linked to the playerId, but when he closes the app (no matter how he does it, since on mobile phones this can be done in many ways), you should call the function that unlink the user from playerId so that it no longer receives chat notifications!

My question is, how can I perform this function whenever the app is closed?

I want to do this because the user can access the system on different smartphones.

I thought of WillPopScope but this only detects when the return baton is fired.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try listening for lifecycle event for an application

https://medium.com/pharos-production/flutter-app-lifecycle-4b0ab4a4211a

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  LifecycleEventHandler({this.resumeCallBack, this.suspendingCallBack});

  final AsyncCallback resumeCallBack;
  final AsyncCallback suspendingCallBack;

  @override
  Future<Null> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        await suspendingCallBack();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        await resumeCallBack();
        break;
    }
  }
}


class AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(
    new LifecycleEventHandler(resumeCallback(() => setState((){}))
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to use AppLifecycleState, but in my case it was not much, since it doesn't have something like an OnDistroy ().
But thanks for the suggestion!